# Getting More Power out of an H-Bridge

Tags: circuit-design, h-bridge, powermosfet

tl;dr: how to design an h-bridge to give more power to motors. pre-fab circuits are not an option.

Hi, so for my electronics class we have to build robots from scratch. So no pre-fab circuits (with the exception of Op-amps if that helps any).

Anyways, I'm running into a problem with driving the motors. I've built a basic h-bridge (see schematic), but the loss from the h-bridge is way too much. I've seen other posts about the issue, but the solution is always about buying a different h-bridge package. Not only would this be disallowed, but I'm also generally curious about the raw design aspects of h-bridges.

so I was wondering what can I do from a component level to get more power delivered to my motors? Would adding some sort of Output stage help?

H-bridge schematic, LEDs as stand in for motors:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for reading.

edit: additional info:
@5V Vcc, the motor observed 2.80V and 0.64V (drawing ~160mA)
no significant drop across the FETs was observed.
the IRF9530 is a P-type power FET, the IRF520 is a N-type power FET

Comment: At what gate voltage (Vgs) si the RDS(on) specified for your FETs? What is that RDS(on) value? Does it account for your observed loss?

Comment: So the Vgs they used to measure the RDS is 10V on both the P & F FETs. The RDS for both is around ~0.3 Ohms. I didn't measure hardly any voltage drop across the Drain-Source, both sitting pretty darn close to the their respective rail voltages. however the voltages sitting on each terminal of the motor while it was on were a quite a bit off. @5V Vcc, the motor observed 2.80V and 0.64V (drawing ~160mA). So like half the voltage is getting lost there. I have a pretty poor understanding of motors, but I think that's to be expected?

Comment: Great job getting measurements and updating the question with the information. A question I had - if the losses aren't in the hbridge as evidence by your measurements of Vds,  why is your question about an h bridge? Are R3/R4 supposed to be representing motor windings?

Comment: Thanks, least I can do for people giving out help ;)
That's a good point, I just assumed I was missing something my h-bridge design. I'm using the chassis from an RC tank. I figured if I couldn't drive the same motors with the same supply that powered it before I gutted all the circuitry then I must be having efficiency issues with my h-bridge. Maybe the breadboard is adding a lot of parasitic impedance or perhaps they had something else in the circuit that allowed for a 4.8V battery pack to drive it? Anyways, thank you for the insight, I can at least check that off my troubleshooting list.

Comment: oh and no, R3 & R4 were just there as placeholders, I didn't go through all the trouble of trying to determine a proper motor model in multisim.

Comment: D1-D4 just duplicate MOSFET diodes. And may be problem with trough currents then two transistor both on for short time at switching moment.

Comment: _"no significant drop across the FETs was observed... Maybe the **breadboard** is adding a lot of parasitic impedance"_ - breadboards are notorious for for having high resistance connections. Measure _all_ the voltages around the circuit and you will find out where that 2.2V went.

Comment: Since VCC < Vgs to guarantee the FETs are fully ON. I would have no expectation this would work. If it does, you got lucky. There ARE FETs with Rds(on) measured at 5V : they would be a better choice. As Bruce says, if you didn't measure losses in the FETs, check teh breadboard and wiring.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I'll try taking out the redundancy diodes. I was told by the prof that we should use them when dealing with motors to add more protection to the FETs, but it's probably not necessary. I'll also try checking all the voltages.

Comment: Brian, are you saying that I should be running Vgs at what the manufacturer used for testing? The Vgs(on) for these FETs are around 2V as printed on the datasheet. Is it just good practice to use FETs relatively close to the manufacturer's testing parameters?

Comment: `Vgs(on) for these FETs are around 2V as printed on the datasheet` can you cite/hyperlink said datasheets? in the IRF520 datasheet [downloadable from Innfineon](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/mosfet/n-channel/irf520n/), I neither expect nor find a \$V_{GS(on)}\$ - same for IRF9530. What I do find is a \$V_{GS(th)}\$ of 2/3/4 Volts min/typ/max. The useful way to think about \$V_{GS(th)}\$ is \$V_{GS(\text{off})}\$ : off statically at less \$V_{GS}\$.

Comment: Another useful information is the \$I_D/V_{DS}\$ at different \$V_{GS}\$ diagram(s) - I find the voltage to allow twice the continuous \$I_D\$ max at 25°C interesting. About 7.5 Volts for the IRF520 - *typical*. *More than 10* for the IRF9530.